# Fragment tab listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, listeners

I got a page view with 3 fragments,  and all 3 use some part of the same list,  should I use a listener in my activity so I can update the list,  or should I make the list public and access it by a method? 
*updated*
And if i use a observer listener, how would i implement it.
Have the activity the listener and the fragments as observers? or do i have the fragments be an observer aswell?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer the listener way.
If you change the list directly, other fragments will not know to update their UI

Comment: That what I was thinking aswell but was not sure if it would be the correct way.  Thank you.